# Redirect calls to implementation for Moq's mock on interface

Tags: mocking, moq

I have an interface

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Int();
    string String();
}
```

and some implementation

```
public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public int Int()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public string String()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to create a mock using Moq for `IFoo`, but if there's no `Setup` provided the mock should call the implementation in `FooImpl`. So far I tried playing with `CallBase` but without success.

```
var mockBase = new Mock<FooImpl>();
var mock = mockBase.As<IFoo>();
mock.CallBase = true;

mock.Setup(x => x.Int()).Returns(10);
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.Int());
Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.String());
```

With this setup I'd like to get `10` (value from `Setup`) and `foo` (the `FooImpl`'s implementation).

I can create the instance of `FooImpl` on the side, mock `IFoo` and delegate all calls there first and then do the `Setup` calls. But that seems to be unnecessary work especially for bigger interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

`CallBase` does not work here since the mock object could not override the `String()` method, since it's not `virtual`.

Change your class to

```
public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    public virtual int Int()
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public virtual string String()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

and it will work as expected.

Comment: I cannot change `FooImpl`. Looks like I'm left with redirecting the calls manually.

Comment: Something is sounding wrong. If really want the concrete implementation to be called why mock it in the first place? What is the external dependency that you are trying to mock?